# Send WhatsApp message to all WhatsApp contacts and text message to the rest of the contacts

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger

I want to send a message to all my contacts, but I want to send a WhatsApp message to those who use WhatsApp and a regular text message to the others. How do I do it?

(I have 1,140 contacts, out of which 662 also use WhatsApp, doing it manually will take a lot of time)

Comment: I don't think a premade kit to do it exists.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using hike(Best way to do this),whereas hike supports sms by the hike number....

Any how you need it in the whatsapp...
 so all you need is to create a broadcast list with all your contacts in it (broadcast messages will be sent to only the contacts who have saved your number in their contact list).

But to send the messages to those who dont have whatsapp you will need some contact app with specific filter...(search in play store)